# When I start XTerm, my .bashrc doesn't get sourced

Tags: bash, xterm

My `~/.bashrc`: https://pastebin.com/VA7RLA2E

My `~/.Xresources`: https://pastebin.com/qSF1z0w4

How do I make XTerm automatically source `.bashrc` when it starts?
Currently, whenever I open a new XTerm window, it doesn't source `~/.bashrc`.

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: a quick google search found this ..... i do not know if it applies to your system .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931378/local-bashrc-is-not-read-on-startup-under-mobaxterm-home-on-windows

Comment: Is bash your default shell ? bash source .bashrc not Xterm.

Comment: @ctac_ Yes. I also checked it with `echo $SHELL` and it says `/bin/bash`.

Comment: @jsotola Oh, that worked. I've put the code in my `.bash_profile` and it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `~/.Xresources` file, you have the line

```
xterm*loginShell: true
```

This would make XTerm start the shell session as a login shell.  When `bash` runs as a login shell, it reads your `~/.bash_profile` file, but it does not read `~/.bashrc` (this file is read by non-login interactive sessions) unless `~/.bash_profile` reads it with `source` explicitly.

You have two options:

1. Remove the line from `~/.Xresources` that specifies that the shell should be a login shell. You will likely have to exit your graphical login session for this file to be re-read and for the changes to take effect.
2. Make your `~/.bash_profile` file `source` your `~/.bashrc` file, while making sure that your `~/.bashrc` file is not sourcing the `~/.bash_profile` file at the same time (which would create an infinite loop).

   An example of how you may do this (this would be added to the `~/.bash_profile` file):

   ```
   if [ -o interactive ] && [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
      source ~/.bashrc
   fi
   ```

   You may need to do something similar for `/etc/profile` vs `/etc/bash.bashrc`, or wherever the system's `bashrc` is on your system if not already done by your system. However, as `/etc/profile` is read by all Bourne-like shells, not just `bash`, it needs to be adapted a little:

   ```
   if [ -n "$BASH" ] &&
      [ "$BASH" != /bin/sh ] &&
      [ -o interactive ] &&
      [ ! -o posix ] &&
      [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]
   then
     source /etc/bash.bashrc
   fi
   ```

Comment: Ok, I did that. I used the second solution. It worked. About the first one, I don't know which line specifies that the shell should be a login shell, so I didn't do that.

Comment: @盧芹達 I mentioned the line at the start of the answer. It says `xterm*loginShell: true`.  For the record, I would probably solve it by the second alternative too, if it was my issue.

Comment: @Kusalanada So, I tried doing that. I removed the things from my ~/.bash_profile that I just added and tried removing the line `xterm*loginShell: true`, but it didn't work. So I ended up still using the second solution.

Comment: @盧芹達, `~/.Xresources` is typically a file that you load at X11 login time into your X server with `xrdb`, that's not a file read by xterm, xterm retrieves those resources from the X server. That's a way to configure xterm on your display regardless of where the xterm connects from. You'd need to restart your X session for those settings to take effect or run `xrdb` again. For a file that xterm reads upon startup, look at `~/.Xdefaults`

Comment: @盧芹達 Run `xrdb -query` to see the list of resources currently loaded into your X server, and `appres xterm` and `appres XTerm` for the resources for xterm instances or the XTerm class.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas .Xdefaults is never read unless you set XENVIRONMENT to point to it. The default file is $HOME/.Xdefaults-<hostname>.

Comment: @ctac_ On what system?

Comment: @Kusalananda on OpenBSD 6.4 GENERIC.MP#364 amd64, on Linux 4.18.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.18.10-2 (2018-11-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux and NetBSD 7.1 (GENERIC.201703111743Z) amd64.

Comment: @ctac_, yes, you're right; at some point, I had to make a `~/.Xdefaults-hostname` symlink to `.Xdefaults` on Linux as well, I don't remember when that changed, but it was a long time ago.

Comment: @ctac_, actually, I still find that xterm reads `.Xdefaults` if there's no resource in the X server and `${XENVIRONMENT-.Xdefaults-$(uname -n)}` otherwise.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, Yes i read that somewhere but it's difficult to have no resource in the X server. I try to log in OpenBSD in twm with startx and .Xdefaults is not read.:)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, sorry .Xdefault is read. forget to uncomment the line Xcalc.customization: -color.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I look more on that. You can have the two files. .Xdefaults-hostname is always read first. .Xdefauts is read only if there is no resources. You can override something defined in .Xdefaults-hostname with .Xdefaults.

Comment: @ctac_, you're right, looks like I misread my `strace xlogo` tests earlier. `.Xdefaults` takes over the missing resources in the X server. So having them both symlinked is probably not such a good idea as the means the file is read twice if there's no resource loaded in the X server. Looking at the XFree86 code from around 1996 (when I started using Unix), it looks like it was already like that, so my earlier claim it changed was probably wrong.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, a good topic on that https://superuser.com/questions/243914/xresources-or-xdefaults

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

- Make sure .bashrc is in your home folder
- Make sure that it is owned by you

  ```
  xterm -e bash --rcfile /home/someuser/.bashrc
  ```